# Is sideloading same as flashing via custom recovery?

Tags: rom-flashing, side-loading

Recently, I side-loaded the latest nougat release on my nexus 6p. Which was almost identical to how one would go about flashing via recovery. This brings me to the question- is there any off  the hand differences between side-loading a zip file against flashing it?

Comment: If you're speaking of `adb sideload` (which I assume), AFAIK the difference is you save yourself some steps: instead of manually copying the `.zip` to the device, booting into recovery, selecting "update from zip", navigate to the zip and finally select it – you simply tell the device to perform all those steps automatically by `adb sideload rom.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

ROM Flashing refers to flashing the OS ROM. Usually involves installing a new image of the OS.

Side-loading usually refers to installing a single app that is not delivered from the Google Play Store (or whatever the app store your device is setup to use.) It can still flash ROMS, but it requires the process of using adb. Good for devices with limited storage, since the ROM can be on the PC with adb rather than the device, but sorta identical to Flashing otherwise.

Comment: While this was my first thought, "sideloading" is rather an ambiguous term. What OP most likely referred to was using the `adb sideload` command – not "installing apps from unknown sources" :)

Comment: Hello Izzy - yes. adb sideload